# Regarding database connections(DB2)

Tags: database, db2

How can I use jdbc driver classname with its schema, username and password to connect to database and retrieve values accordingly?

Example:

```
getConnection(jdbc://bea...IP address/schema(like port)/username(admin)/passwrd)
```

Does this code give a connection to particular DB? If yes, please help me with a sample code. Am learning these days and working on a small tool.

Comment: What platform is DB/2 running on?  Which JDBC driver are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

First,

I think you should use type 4 driver.

This is how it works:
jdbc:db2://server:port/dbname

The access or grants given to the schema are defined in the system tables... 
and I have never seen the possibility of connecting to a particular schema.

you could always connect like this using a properties file:

```
Class.forName(ressources.getString("dbDriver").trim()).newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ressources.getString("urlConnection").trim(),
                                           ressources.getString("user").trim(),
                                           ressources.getString("psswd").trim());
```

or like this using hibernate :

```
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver">com.ibm.DB2.jcc.DB2Driver</property>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user">user</property>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password">password</property>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url">jdbc:db2://server:port/dbname</property>
```